# Returning an obejct which is created inside a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

when I create an object inside a function it should be automatically deleted when the function exists. e.g. the object F should be automatically deleted when getFoo() exits. However still we are able to access F when we call getFoo. How?

```
     Foo getFoo()
     {    Foo F;
          return F;
     }
```

Comment: Do you get confused by `int main()`? How does `main()` return an `int` object to the caller?

Comment: You are returning a **copy** of `f` (possibly move constructed, but that's not really relevant, so don't worry if you don't know what I mean).

Comment: syntactically you are returning a copy, RVO allows the complier to construct the object directly at its destination and avoids the copy

Comment: You might want to look at [shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: @Koning How are pointers (of any kind) relevant to this?

Comment: @Angew With shared pointers you can create an object inside a function and return it so that another object can take ownership of it.

Comment: @Koning You mean `unique_ptr` (I hope)? Still not really relevant here.

Comment: @Koning And without them you can just create an object inside a function and return it to the caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not accessing the object which was created inside the function. A copy is made on the stack before returning from the function. And of course the object which was created inside the function scope was destroyed when the function returned. By destruction, I mean the location on the stack on which it existed is no more valid.

Comment: Except if RVO takes place, then the object created inside the function and the one accessed by the caller are one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

The object is copied to the caller.

Theoretically the following code

```
Foo a = getFoo();
```

- calls the function
- F is constructed
- a is copy-constructed from F
- F is destroyed

even funnier is this

```
Foo b;
b = getFoo();
```

- b is constructed
- calls the function
- F is constructed
- unnamed temporary object (temp) is copy-constructed from F
- F is destroyed
- assignment operator is called from temp to b
- temp is destroyed.

Thankfully modern compiler support return value optimization to prevent this.
This also is also one of the very few exceptions to the "as if" mantra regarding code-optimizations.

You may test this with your favorite debuger with this example code (tip: note the addresses of the objects):

```
struct A {
  A() {
    i = 0; 
  }
  A(const A& o) {
    i = o.i;
  }

  A& operator=(A& o) {
    i = o.i;
    return *this;
  }

  ~A() {
    i = 0;
  }
  int i;
};

A getA() {
  A a;
  return a;
}

int main(){
  A a = getA();
  A b;
  b = getA();

  return 0;
}
```